# jQuery object reference is empty

Tags: jquery

```
var quiz = {

    config : {
        qType : $j('#questionTypeDdown')
    },

    data : {
        qType : 'test'
    },

    init: function() {
        quiz.assignUIActions();
    },

    assignUIActions : function() {

        var c = quiz.config;
        var d = quiz.data;

        quiz.assignqType(c,d);
    },

    assignqType : function(c,d) {
        console.log(c.qType);
        console.log(d.qType);
    }
};

$j(document).ready(function() { quiz.init(); });
```

`console.log(c.qType)` returns an empty jQuery object but

`console.log(d.qType)` returns the value 'test'

Please explain why this is happening and what is the right way to get reference to `#questionTypeDdown`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running `qType : $j('#questionTypeDdown')` before the document is loaded.

You need to execute your object initializer in `$j(document).ready`.

Comment: see last line $j(document).ready(function() { quiz.init(); });

Comment: @Adi: `qType : $j('#questionTypeDdown')` runs _immediately_, not when you call your `init` function.

Comment: are you suggesting to move the whole quiz object inside document.ready? How can I make sure the qType : $j('#questionTypeDdown') happens on document ready only?

Comment: Yes; that's exactly what I'm suggesting.